# How to repack vmlinux.elf back to bzimage file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

#### Background

I was trying to made some modifications directly on kernel static binary file(bzimage) got from some IOT devices. There's no original compile environment of linux kernel. Here're my steps:

- Step 1:Use [extract-vmlinux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6aeadf7896bff4ca230702daba8788455e6b866e/scripts/extract-vmlinux#L4) or [vmlinux-to-elf](https://github.com/marin-m/vmlinux-to-elf) to extract `vmlinux.elf` from bzimage file(we call the bzimage file from IOT device `bzimage_origin` later.)
- Step 2:Use disassembly tools like `IDA PRO` or `Ghidra` to analyze target `vmlinux.elf` file. Use plugin like `keypatch` to modify program control flow statically. Then we got new vmlinux file `vmlinux.elf_patched`
- Step 3:Trying to repack `vmlinux.elf_patched` back to bzimage file `bzimage_output`

Problem occurs when trying step 3.

#### Description

Apologies for the confusion of summarizing the problem title. There maybe two problems but solving each of them is enough.

- How to repack vmlinux.elf back to bzimage file?
- How to use repo [recreate-zImage](https://github.com/kiler129/recreate-zImage) to generate `VGA Normal` output mode bzimage kernel file?

#### Trial

A repo on github may help. repo link: [recreate-zImage](https://github.com/kiler129/recreate-zImage)

The repo contributes to repack bzimage file from original compiled bzimage file from source. If i can replace the `vmlinux.elf` after the tool extract it from `bzimage_origin`. The problem solved.

But after using the tool(a shell script `recreate-zimage.sh`). The output bzimage is different from the original one. Let's see the `file` command output.

```
# file ./*
../bzimage_origin:          Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 3.2.16 (root@ubuntu) #0 SMP Tue Jan 31 04:39:01 UTC 2023, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x3, Normal VGA
../bzimage_output:       Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 3.2.16 (root@ubuntu) #0 SMP Tue Jun 27 19:39:52 PDT 2023, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x3, Prompt for Videomode
```

The first is origin one which compiled from source. And the second is the recompiled version which is the output of `recreate-zimage.sh` (with Linux source code 3.2.16). Notice that the second one different from the first for their output mode.

i 've tried following ways to change its output mode. but failed.

[Details Graphics support settings](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/72cc788e46a65e3c4b56883e28d7e1cbf1dd4e17f1388ccbaf86724510cef619/68747470733a2f2f692e706f7374696d672e63632f3372445a344b38382f536e6970617374652d323032332d30362d32382d30302d34352d31342e706e67)

- Edit options in `make menuconfig`. Go to "Device Drivers" -> "Graphics support". Disable most options which may be related to Videomode. Choices set as above. However... not work.
- Try to directly disable driver mode in `.config` file. i commented option `CONFIG_VIDEO_OUTPUT_CONTROL` in .config. However, mysterious power sliently modified the option in `.config` back to previous after executing the shell script.
- Debug the shell script and try to find some clues. i used `bash -x` option to debug the script and notice that shared library related to video mode are used. it can be proved by part of the debug output below. but i have no idea what is the next step.

```
+ SETUP_ELF_OBJS='arch/x86/boot/a20.o arch/x86/boot/bioscall.o arch/x86/boot/cmdline.o arch/x86/boot/copy.o arch/x86/boot/cpu.o arch/x86/boot/cpucheck.o arch/x86/boot/early_serial_console.o arch/x86/boot/edd.o arch/x86/boot/header.o arch/x86/boot/main.o arch/x86/boot/mca.o arch/x86/boot/memory.o arch/x86/boot/pm.o arch/x86/boot/pmjump.o arch/x86/boot/printf.o arch/x86/boot/regs.o arch/x86/boot/string.o arch/x86/boot/tty.o arch/x86/boot/video.o arch/x86/boot/video-mode.o arch/x86/boot/version.o arch/x86/boot/video-vga.o arch/x86/boot/video-vesa.o arch/x86/boot/video-bios.o  '
```

#### Reproduce

##### systeminfo

```
# uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-148-generic #165~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 01:14:06 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

##### reproduce steps

Whatever the origin compiled bzimage file(you can compile a VGA-normal-output bzimage file from Linux source code and assume that you don't have the original environment). To reproduce the problem. You need to take steps below:

- Step 1: Download the same version of linux kernel source code.(Here my bzimage kernel file is [Linux 3.2.16](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.2.16.tar.gz) ). Make sure that you have installed dependencies to build linux kernel like `build-essential`.
- Step 2: Add `-fno-pie` in KBUILD_FLAGS to solve the kernel building does not support PIE error
- Step 3: Copy `include/linux/compiler-gcc4.h` in linux kernel source code to `include/linux/compiler-gcc7.h`. I build the kernel on Ubuntu 18.04 and default gcc version is 7.5. So `include/linux/compiler-gcc7.h` is necessary for building.
- Step 4: Run command `./rebuild_kernel.sh KERNEL_SRC_ROOT BZIMGAE_ORIGIN_PATH BZIMAGE_OUTPUT_PATH`

#### Tips

- both solving problems of this repo or giving other ways to repack `vmlinux.elf` are OK.
- Thanks for your help.

Comment: Kernel is distributed under GPLv2 terms, the binary provider MUST provide a source code if asked. So, go and ask for the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, and I have managed to do it successfully. But it takes some effort. Here are some things I would suggest keeping in mind.

1. Figure out the Image format that you are extracting from. If you do a binwalk on `bzImage`, you'll see compressed images at various locations. Also shameless plug for https://github.com/Caesurus/extract-vmlinux-v2, which might be of some use...
2. manually extract the kernel `vmlinux` from the `bzImage`. You'll need to figure out exactly what compression was used so you can recompress it later
3. while you can use `vmlinux-to-elf` to create an ELF file that contains symbols, you should only use that as a reference for debugging/analysis with Binary Ninja, Ghidra, IDA etc... Don't try to modify the resulting elf file and packing it back up.
4. modify the extracted vmlinux in the tool of your choice, patch asm etc...
5. when you're done, save the binary, compress it again with exactly the same options as the original, and replace the data in the original `bzImage` file.

For step `2`, I would recommend looking at the kernel sources to determine specific flags for compression, and make sure that you can uncompress and recompress without making any changes to the file. The recompressed file should be identical to the original compressed version.

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but hopefully helpful to someone in the future. I may at some point do a writeup with examples since it's pretty fun and interesting.

Step by Step Write-Up here:

https://github.com/Caesurus/CTF_Writeups/blob/main/2024-04-zImageKernelPatch/README.MD

Additionally, this most excellent article covering the case when you're growing the original image:

https://jamchamb.net/2022/01/02/modify-vmlinuz-arm.html